# Application supports more than one language?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [internationalization of an iPhone Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580144/internationalization-of-an-iphone-application)

I know that its possible to create application that will support multilanguage, how can I manage to do it? I want my application to support for an example English and Hebrew (also they are RTL and LTR - that's another problem I think, right?).

I'm new to objective-c, please be gentle... haha

Thanks

---

Thanks all of you guys! I just love this website. greatest people.

Comment: this question may help you! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451776/best-way-to-make-an-iphone-application-multi-lingual

Comment: there are several existing questions on iOS and Internationalization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a good tutorial here:

http://www.ibabbleon.com/iphone_app_localization.html